# compile dll with external cs file dependency

Tags: c#, dll, dependencies

I am trying to share my code's capabilities with another person, while obfuscating the actual code (via dll). However, my library depends on a (free) 3rd party piece of code that cannot be distributed in my package due to licensing, but both of us have - let's call it "sharedfile.cs"

Question: Is it possible for me to create a DLL of my code that depends on the existence of "sharedfile.cs", while not rolling that file into my dll?

If not... what options would be available? Both of us have "sharedfile.cs" but I do not want to expose my raw code by not creating a DLL.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Compiling into a DLL isn't really going to stop anyone from accessing your code. For example, ILSpy is totally free and can be used to snoop around your code incredibly easily. Doesn't really answer your question, but it's worth pointing out.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb I understand that, I'm not trying to hide it from really smart or resourceful people, I'm trying to make it difficult. But that's neither here nor there in regards to the question. :)